# How to turn a dataframe to jsonl with similar index for every line?

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonlines

I have `dataframe` that has "input" as the index of all of the rows. Thousands of them.

```
  df1 = 
  index   item name   item quantity
  input       apple         4
  input       orange        3
  input       lemon         6
```

I need to turn it to a `jsonl` file looking like this. I need it looking like this because of the requirement in Shopify GraphQL Admin API Bulk import.

```
{ "input": { "item name": "apple", "item quantity": "4"}}
{ "input": { "item name": "orange", "item quantity": "3"}}
{ "input": { "item name": "lemon", "item quantity": "6"}}
```

I can use `df1.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)` to convert it into `jsonl`  without the index to look like this

```
{ "item name": "apple", "item quantity": "4"}}
{ "item name": "orange", "item quantity": "3"}}
{ "item name": "lemon", "item quantity": "6"}}
```

But i will need to add the key "input" to the front which i dont know how to do it. I am new to json.

I also tried `df1.to_json(orient="index")` but it gives me an error `ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'` indicating that every index must be unique.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Hi, is index a column name, or the original index

Comment: Hiiii. Its the original index. I can also make it a normal column i think it doesnt really matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your required output is:

```
{ "input": { "item name": "apple", "item quantity": "4"}}
{ "input": { "item name": "orange", "item quantity": "3"}}
{ "input": { "item name": "lemon", "item quantity": "6"}}
```

orient='index' won't work in this case because index are not unique. The above answer looks great. Your expected output is seperate JSONs.

This is a workaround, According to your required format incase if you need the same format itself

```
import pandas as pd
import json
data=[['apple',4],['orange','3'],['lemon',6]]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['item name','item quantity'])
json_as_str=df.to_json(orient="index")
json_value=json.loads(json_as_str)
string_formatted=[]
for key,val in json_value.items():
    string_formatted.append("{'input':%s}" %val)
with open("file_name_here.jsonl","a") as fh:
    for i in string_formatted:
        i=i.replace("'",'"')
        fh.write(f"{i}\n")
```

Output:

```
{"input":{"item name": "apple", "item quantity": 4}}
{"input":{"item name": "orange", "item quantity": 3}}
{"input":{"item name": "lemon", "item quantity": 6}}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn all the output into one jsonl file instead of printed out as strings 1 by 1?

Comment: Hi @JJasperr Edited the answer. Now will write to a file

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you kind sir